# Validation Controls in User Control not stopping page postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp button and a user control containing custom validator in it when i click the button that is present on the page not inside the usercontrol, the user control client side validation occurs and displays the javascript method regarding data entry failure but when i click the javascript alert box ok button, the postback gets occured automatically i want to stop the postback if the user control contains invalid data in iother words the postback get occured only when the user control contains the valid data.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I have already done this type of coding in javascript:

```
    function CheckTimeRangeTo_9(sender, args) {

    var e = document.getElementById('<%= ddTimeTableTo_9.ClientID %>');

    var totalToTimeInMins = CalculateTotalMinutes(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
    var totalFromTimeInMins = CalculateTotalMinutes(args.Value);

    if (totalToTimeInMins != 0 && totalToTimeInMins < totalFromTimeInMins) {
        alert("From time cannot be greater than to time in time slice ID 9.");
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }

    args.IsValid = true;
}
```

Comment: Hey, for testing purposes, try commenting everything out and just have args.IsValid = false;, make sure that works.  If that fails, then we know its related to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you shouldn't return anything here. I mean `return;` in function CheckTimeRangeTo_9 shouldn't be here. And `args.IsValid = true;` should be inside else statement. So, you should try:

```
function CheckTimeRangeTo_9(sender, args) {

    var e = document.getElementById('<%= ddTimeTableTo_9.ClientID %>');

    var totalToTimeInMins = CalculateTotalMinutes(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
    var totalFromTimeInMins = CalculateTotalMinutes(args.Value);

    if (totalToTimeInMins != 0 && totalToTimeInMins < totalFromTimeInMins) {
        alert("From time cannot be greater than to time in time slice ID 9.");
        args.IsValid = false;        
    }
   else
   {
       args.IsValid = true;
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i have adjusted the code according to your suggestion but the problem is not solved event with it, it continues to postback after displaying the javascript alert message box.

Comment: I think we need to identify which element or script function cause this postback. You can start debugging on the web application and add some break points in some postback event handlers and other page events to see whether the strange postback will hit into any of the breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set `IsValid` property of the parameter which is passed to your client-side validation function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myValidator_ClientValid(sender, args) {
      var valid = false;

      // Perform validation

      args.IsValid = valid;
    }
</script>
```